# Grab an ID from particular array index

Tags: json, swift

I have some **JSON** which returns the following:

```
"data": [
{
  "created_time": "2010-09-03T16:07:14+0000",
  "name": "Profile Pictures",
  "id": "125287297520173"
},
{
  "created_time": "2010-12-03T00:05:31+0000",
  "name": "Mobile Uploads",
  "id": "146617845387118"
},
{
  "created_time": "2013-07-27T11:34:50+0000",
  "name": "Timeline Photos",
  "id": "546011742114391"
},
{
  "created_time": "2017-01-04T19:02:40+0000",
  "name": "Untitled Album",
  "id": "1178578645524361"
},
{
  "created_time": "2016-09-10T18:26:25+0000",
  "name": "Untitled Album",
  "id": "1076646985717528"
},
{
  "created_time": "2016-07-06T18:27:09+0000",
  "name": "OS X Photos",
  "id": "1033031426745751"
},
{
  "created_time": "2013-06-22T07:32:01+0000",
  "name": "iOS Photos",
  "id": "530462737002625"
},
{
  "created_time": "2012-05-22T19:01:42+0000",
  "name": "Cover Photos",
  "id": "370987619616805"
},
{
  "created_time": "2015-08-27T18:59:56+0000",
  "name": "Untitled Album",
  "id": "879780692070826"
},
{
  "created_time": "2014-12-06T16:13:01+0000",
  "name": "DRMC 2005 Batch",
  "id": "761469943901902"
},
{
  "created_time": "2013-06-16T09:01:17+0000",
  "name": "Instagram Photos",
  "id": "528368577212041"
},
{
  "created_time": "2012-09-09T17:37:55+0000",
  "name": "Liverpool Exclusive",
  "id": "416230538425846"
},
{
  "created_time": "2012-09-10T16:31:52+0000",
  "name": "LIVERPOOL FC TOUR",
  "id": "416540875061479"
},
{
  "created_time": "2010-06-11T19:37:20+0000",
  "name": "cars",
  "id": "104577376257832"
},
{
  "created_time": "2011-03-29T23:50:18+0000",
  "name": "Camera+ Photos",
  "id": "174268382622064"
}
]
```

I would like to grab the **id** of the field **"name": "Profile Pictures"** . I am using **SwiftyJSON** to cast the types and so far I managed to do this :

```
 let dictionary = JSON(result)
 // print("albums **************\(dictionary)")
 if let data = dictionary["data"].array {
 print("data of profilePicture ******* \(data)")
 let index = data.index{ $0["name"] == "Profile Pictures" }

  }
 }
```

I could detech the **name** of **profilePicture** as you can see but now I want to grab the **id** of that json object. Please help.

Comment: You wants to fetch only one **id** then   `var myId: String? = (yourArrayName[0]["id"] as? String) ` hope this will help you. OR you can fetch it by using for in loop.

Comment: yes @Mukesh I tried that and I got the result as expected as well, but how can I be sure that the **JSON** will return in **[0]th** index my desired id, this might return in other index. Thats why I make sure that I grabbed the **id** where **name: Profile Picture** because I want **id** of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let dictionary = JSON(result)
// print("albums ID are **************\(dictionary)")
if let data = dictionary["data"].array {
print("data of profilePicture ******* \(data)")

if let dict = data.first(where: { ($0["name"].string ) == "Profile Pictures" }) {
         let id = dict["id"]
         print("my desired id : ********* \(id)")
       }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` to get the dictionary you're interested in…

```
let dictionary = JSON(result)
// print("albums **************\(dictionary)")
if let data = dictionary["data"].array {
    print("data of profilePicture ******* \(data)")

    if let dict = data.filter{ $0["name"] == "Profile Pictures" }.first as? [String: String] {
       let id = dict["id"]
    }
}
```

Comment: there was some problem , although your answer helped me to solve the issue, thank you

Comment: A chained `filter` and `first` applied to a non-lazy collection (e.g. an array, as above) is generally wasteful, as you can simply apply [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first) (using the predicate you use in the `filter`) directly instead, allowing short-circuiting.